# Proxy server on Heroku

Tags: heroku, ip

There is an addon on Heroku called Proximo, and I'm just curious what kind of server you would need to setup to run your own proxy?  Would Squid do the same thing that Proximo is doing or does anyone have any experience/suggestions for how to setup one up?

Our app vitally needs a dedicated IP address and proximo is a bit expensive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either [**Squid**](http://www.squid-cache.org/), [**Haproxy**](http://haproxy.1wt.eu/) or even [**nginx**](http://nginx.org/) - they are all high-throughput and very stable proxy/caching solutions.